# Syntax error, unexpected keyword_end and unexpected end_of_input

Tags: ruby

[image]

I don't know why i am getting this error

Comment: Questions about syntax errors don't do well here, because they are unlikely to be of general value to the community.  That said, for the next question, could you please put the code in the question as code, rather than as an image?  Images can't be searched, we can't cute-and-paste them, and so on.  Also, you hopefully have a stack trace identifying the lines that caused the syntax error.  The stack trace would be good to have in the question also.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Read "[ask]" including the linked pages and "[mcve]". Please do _NOT_ use an image to convey code or data that is necessary to duplicate a problem. We can't copy and paste it to reuse it, nor can search engines use it to help direct others with the same problem to your question. Also, links to images can rot then break, and, at that point your question will be worthless to others.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`++` operator doesn't exist in Ruby. Just use `+= 1`.